# Problem when trying to use prism to create an API with nodeTs

Tags: node.js, prisma

how are you? I'm trying to use prism and node to create an api, but when I test it with insomnia,the following error occurs:

```
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/Users/eduard/Documents/Programação/Sites/primeiros-projetos/sistema-de-cadastro-de-usuarios/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:160:10)
    at parse (/Users/eduard/Documents/Programação/Sites/primeiros-projetos/sistema-de-cadastro-de-usuarios/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /Users/eduard/Documents/Programação/Sites/primeiros-projetos/sistema-de-cadastro-de-usuarios/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:128:18
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/eduard/Documents/Programação/Sites/primeiros-projetos/sistema-de-cadastro-de-usuarios/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:231:16)
    at done (/Users/eduard/Documents/Programação/Sites/primeiros-projetos/sistema-de-cadastro-de-usuarios/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:220:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/eduard/Documents/Programação/Sites/primeiros-projetos/sistema-de-cadastro-de-usuarios/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:280:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:475:12)
```

can anybody help me?

this is my code:

server.ts:

```
import express, {Response, Request} from "express";
import "express-async-errors"
import { routes } from "./routes";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())

app.use(routes)

app.listen(3333, () => {
    console.log("O servidor está rodando na porta 3333: http://localhost:3333")
})
```

createUserUseCase.ts:

```
import { createUserDTO } from "../../usersDTOS/createUserDTO";
import { prisma } from "../../../../prismaClient/client";
import { Users } from "@prisma/client";

export class CreateUserUseCase {
    async execute({ name, email, password }: createUserDTO): Promise<Users> {
      const userAlreadyExists = await prisma.users.findUnique({
        where: {
            email: email
        }
        })
        // if (userAlreadyExists) {
        // //throw new AppError("Book Already Exists")
        // }

        const user = await prisma.users.create({
            data: {
                name, 
                email,
                password
            }
        })

        return user
    }

}
```

createUserController.ts:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { CreateUserUseCase } from "./createUserUseCase";

export class CreateUserController {
   async handle(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;

        const createUserUseCase = new CreateUserUseCase();

        const result = await createUserUseCase.execute({ name, email, password })

        return res.status(201).json(result)
    }
}
```

createUserDTO:

```
export interface createUserDTO {
    name: string
    email: string
    password: string
}
```

client.ts:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

export const prisma = new PrismaClient();
```

user.routes.ts:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { CreateUserController } from "../modules/users/useCases/createUserUseCase/createUserController";

const createUserController = new CreateUserController();

const userRoutes = Router()

userRoutes.post("/", createUserController.handle)

export { userRoutes }
```

index.ts:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { userRoutes } from "./user.routes";

const routes = Router();

routes.use("/users", userRoutes)

export { routes }
```

these were the data I put on insomnia for him to make the post:

```
 {
    "name": "Eduard",
    "email": "Eduard@edu.com",
    "password": "1234"
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone can help you without seeing the relevant code that is connected with this error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, based on your code and the stack trace, that you have an incoming request that claims it is `application/json`, but the body content of the request is not legal JSON.  Thus, when the body-parser module (which implements the middleware `express.json()`) tries to parse the incoming JSON, it throws an error.

To track the error source further, we'd need to see the client-side of the request and see how the request is formed and sent.